# stored procedure and trigger MySQL lost data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, auto-increment

First let me explain my System:
I have two equal databases on two systems every 15 minutes the new Data of several tables will be synchronized.

For this I compare the last primary key of the first database with the last on the second. Every new data will be inserted via INSERT-Statement in the second database. The data volume will be at least 200 up to 500 datasets. The Severs with the databases are connected via internet.

The Problem:
On the second databases i have to calculate a value out of two values from different tables and write this in a third db.
So i wrote a stored procedure and call this by a trigger on one of the tables.

But the table with the trigger stores less data than the equivalent on the first Server.
So i think the runtime of the stored procedure causes a data loss. But why? 
On a test system it works but in productive process not.

Another curiosity is that the actual primary key of the databases (auto increment Integer) is the same. But the second db contains less data.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `calcSigma`(IN `val1` DOUBLE(10,2), IN `ident` VARCHAR(20), IN `id` INT(11), IN `ts` DATETIME)
BEGIN   
DECLARE phi, theta, sigma double DEFAULT 0; 
IF ident='x_theta' THEN
    SET theta = val1;
    SET phi = (SELECT
    val
    FROM
    x_phi
    WHERE
    sensors_id = id
    AND 
    HOUR(
        TIMEDIFF(
            ts, ts_rised))='0'
    AND
    MINUTE(
        TIMEDIFF(
            ts, ts_rised))='0'
    ORDER BY
    ts_rised
    DESC LIMIT 1);  END IF;
IF theta<>0 && phi<>0 THEN
    IF theta >= 0 THEN
        SET sigma =(((phi/100)*(288.68*POW(1.098+(theta/100),8.02)))/(461.5*(theta+273.15)));
    ELSEIF theta < 0 THEN
        SET sigma =(((phi/100)*(4.689*POW(1.486+(theta/100),12.3)))/(461.5*(theta+273.15)));
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO 
    x_sigma (ts_rised, val, sensors_id) 
    VALUES (ts, sigma, id);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Firstly, your question seems very long-winded. Telling us that your problem 'works great' seems like there is no actual problem. What you are asking /seems/ like a 'whats your opinion'. Could you not post some relevant data on the structure of the DB, or the procedure you're using?

Comment: Here is the syntax of the procedure: